# Concatenação de ítens de um Array em loop aninhado

Tags: javascript, loop, array-multidimensional

Gostaria de pegar os ítens em `var a`, um Array Bi-dimensional, e fazer uma iteração num loop aninhado, concatenando tudo, a fim de colocá-los entre colchetes, separados por uma barra, como mostra o resultado desejado logo abaixo, que será armazenado em `var b`. O problema é que as barras e os colchetes não ficam do jeito esperado.

```
/* 
Resultado Desejado:
Array [ "[advice / advices]", "[are / is]" ]

Resultado Obtido (Indesejado):
Array [ "[advice /advices /", "[are]is]" ]
*/

var a = [
    ['advice', 'advices'],
    ['are', 'is']
];
var b = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var c = ['['];
    for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

        if (i < a[i].length - 1) {
            c += a[i][j].split(',').toString().trim() + ' /';
        }

        if (i == a[i].length - 1) {
            c += a[i][j].split(',').toString().trim() + ']';
        }
    }
    b.push(c);
}

console.log(b); // Array [ "[advice /advices /", "[are]is]" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é mesmo nos `ifs` que utilizam `i` quando deveriam utilizar `j`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var c = ['['];
    for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

        if (i < a[i].length - 1) {
        //  ^--- aqui devia ser j
            c += a[i][j].split(',').toString().trim() + ' /';
        }

        if (i == a[i].length - 1) {
        //  ^--- e aqui também
            c += a[i][j].split(',').toString().trim() + ']';
        }
    }
    b.push(c);
}
```

Apesar de com esta alteração já funcionar `a[i][j].split(',')` não faz sentido pois `a[i][j]` é uma `String` com um texto como `'advice'`. Logo `split(',')` vai transformar num array apenas com um elemento e o `toString()` a seguir volta a transformar na mesma `String` que tinha originalmente.

Por isso a concatenação deveria ser feita assim:

```
c += a[i][j].trim() + ' /';
```

Mas porquê complicar algo simples ? Utilize o [método `join` de `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) que foi feito exatamente para esse fim, juntar todos os elementos numa só `String` colocando um separador à sua escolha:

```js
var a = [
    ['advice', 'advices'],
    ['are', 'is']
];

var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b.push("[" + a[i].join(' / ') + "]");
}

console.log(b);
```

Mantive o `push` para ficar ao estilo do que tinha.

**Edit**:

Se é necessário aplicar o [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) basta adicionar um `map` antes do `join` para mapear todos os elementos para a sua versão *trimmed*:

```js
var a = [
    ['advice', 'advices'],
    ['are', 'is']
];

var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b.push("[" + a[i].map(x=>x.trim()).join(' / ') + "]");
}

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Isac, ficou perfeita essa sua solução mais simples. O problema é que `var a` é originalmente gerada à partir de uma função que torna as palavras aleatórias, fazendo com que possa haver espaços no início e fim de cada palavra, por isso usei o `trim()`. Ex: `var a = [ ['advice ', ' advices'], [' are', 'is '] ];`. Resultado: `var b = [ '[advice / advices]' '[ are / is ]' ];`. Tem espaço antes de ***are*** e depois de ***is*** e, como é aleatório, `var a` pode acabar com espaços iniciais e finais em qualquer uma das palavras. Tem como aplicar o `trim()` às palavras antes da concatenação.

Comment: @eden Tem sim senhor, basta fazer um `map` antes do `join`. Já editei a resposta para contemplar esse cenário também.

Answer (score 0):

Se a array original for sempre com 2 subitens, pode fazer assim:

```js
var a = [
    ['advice', 'advices'],
    ['are', 'is']
];
var b = [];

a.forEach(function(e){
   b.push('['+e[0]+' / '+e[1]+']');
});
console.log(b);
```